# Solving a Nonlinear System

Tags: numerical-methods

$$\begin{align}
(1/300)a + (-1/200)b &= 5\\
(-1/300)a + ((-1/300) + (1/200))b + (-1/200)c &= -e^b\\
(-1/200)b + (1/200)c &= -e^c
\end{align}
$$
how do I solve for $a, b$ and $c$?
Thanks!

I know if I derive an equation that isolates a variable, like
$kx + e^x = 0$
I can use Newton's  method to approximate x.
But still can't figure it out.

(I am just a high school student - so if you can make your answers as easy to understand as possible)

Comment: Newton's method also works for systems, as you can read [here, for example](http://www.math.ohiou.edu/courses/math344/lecture13.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

Your system

$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{1}{300}a-\frac{1}{200}b=5 \\ 
-\frac{1}{300}a+\left( -\frac{1}{300}+\frac{1}{200}\right) b-\frac{1}{200}
c=-e^{b} \\ 
-\frac{1}{200}b+\frac{1}{200}c=-e^{c}\tag{1}
\end{array}
\right. $$

is equivalent to

$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
2a-3b=3000 \\ 
-2a+b-3c=-600e^{b} \\ 
-b+c=-200e^{c}\tag{2}
\end{array}
\right. $$

and to

$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
a=\frac{3}{2}\left( c+200e^{c}\right) +1500 \\ 
-5c-400e^{c}-3000+600\text{ exp}(c+200e^{c})=0 \\ \tag{3}
b=c+200e^{c}.
\end{array}
\right. $$

The second equation has two solutions ([computation in WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+-5c-400e%5Ec-3000%2B600e%5E%28c%2B200e%5Ec%29%3D0)):
$c\approx -600.000$ and $c\approx -3.64058$.

The Newton's method applied to $$f(c)=-5c-400e^{c}-3000+600\text{ exp}(c+200e^{c})\tag{4}$$

consists of the following iterations

$$c_{k+1}=c_{k}-\frac{f(c_{k})}{f^{\prime }(c_{k})},\qquad k=1,2,\dots\tag{5}$$

with

$$f'(c)=-5-400e^{c}+600\left( 1+200e^{c}\right) \text{ exp}(c+200e^{c})\tag{6}$$

Starting with e.g. $c_{1}=-500$, we get
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(c_{1}) &=&-5c_{1}-400e^{c_{1}}-3000+600\text{ exp}(c_{1}+200e^{c_{1}}) \\
f(-500) &=&5\times 500-400e^{-500}-3000+600\text{ exp}(-500+200e^{-500}) \\
&\approx &-500.0
\end{eqnarray*}$$

and
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
f^{\prime }(c_{1}) &=&-5-400e^{c_{1}}+600\left( 1+200e^{c_{1}}\right)
\text{ exp}(c_{1}+200e^{c_{1}}) \\
f^{\prime }(-500) &=&-5-400e^{-500}+600\left( 1+200e^{-500}\right)
\text{ exp}(-500+200e^{-500}) \\
&\approx &-5.0.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

And so,
$$
c_{2}=c_{1}-\frac{f(c_{1})}{f^{\prime }(c_{1})}\approx -500-\frac{-500.0}{
-5.0}\approx -600.0,
$$

which is already a good approximation.

For $c_{1}=-3.6$, we get successively 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
c_{2} &\approx &-3.6-\frac{879.64}{25019.0}\approx -3.6352 \\
c_{3} &\approx &-3.6352-\frac{71.578}{19406.}\approx -3.6389 \\
c_{4} &\approx &-3.6389-\frac{1.\,417\,3}{18902.}\approx -3.6390 \\
c_{5} &\approx &-3.6390-\frac{29.\,615}{18889.}\approx -3.6406 \\
c_{6} &\approx &-3.6406-\frac{-0.435\,93}{18676}\approx
-3.6406.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

From $(3)$ for $c\approx -3.6406$, we get the solution $(a,b,c)\approx
(1502.4,1.6067,-3.6406)$ and for $c\approx -600.0$ the solution $(a,b,c)\approx
(600.0,-600.0,-600.0)$.

[image]

Plot of $f(c)$ for $c=-700$ to $c=-3.62$

[image]

Plot of $f(c)$ for $c=-3.7$ to $c=-3.6$

---

**Added**: You have perhaps in mind the general method for solving a nonlinear
system, applied to the present case.  Let's denote $x_{1}=a,x_{2}=b,x_{3}=c$. The system

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
f_{1}(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}) \\ 
f_{2}(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}) \\ 
f_{3}(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
0
\end{pmatrix},\tag{7}$$

where

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
f_{1}(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}) \\ 
f_{2}(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}) \\ 
f_{3}(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{300}x_{1}-\frac{1}{200}x_{2}-5 \\ 
-\frac{1}{300}x_{1}+\left( -\frac{1}{300}+\frac{1}{200}\right) x_{2}-\frac{1
}{200}x_{3}+e^{x_{2}} \\ 
-\frac{1}{200}x_{2}+\frac{1}{200}x_{3}+e^{x_{3}}
\end{pmatrix},\tag{8}$$

has the Jacobian matrix

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
J\left( x\right)  &=&
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_{1}(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})}{\partial x_{1}} & \frac{\partial
f_{1}(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})}{\partial x_{2}} & \frac{\partial
f_{1}(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})}{\partial x_{3}} \\ 
\frac{\partial f_{2}(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})}{\partial x_{1}} & \frac{\partial
f_{2}(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})}{\partial x_{2}} & \frac{\partial
f_{2}(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})}{\partial x_{3}} \\ 
\frac{\partial f_{3}(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})}{\partial x_{1}} & \frac{\partial
f_{3}(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})}{\partial x_{2}} & \frac{\partial
f_{3}(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})}{\partial x_{3}}
\end{pmatrix}
\\
&=&
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{300} & -\frac{1}{200} & 0 \\ 
-\frac{1}{300} & \frac{1}{600}+e^{x_{2}} & -\frac{1}{200} \\ 
0 & -\frac{1}{200} & \frac{1}{200}+e^{x_{3}}
\end{pmatrix}
.
\end{eqnarray*}\tag{9}
$$

The Newton's method consists of starting with an approximation $x^{(1)}$ and
find successively

$$x^{(k+1)}=x^{(k)}+\Delta x^{(k)},\qquad k=1,2,\dots\tag{10}$$

where $\Delta x^{(k)}$ is a solution of

$$J\left( x^{(k)}\right) \Delta x^{(k)}=-f\left( x^{(k)}\right) ,\tag{11}$$

which can be found by Gaussian elimination.

*Notation*: $x^{(k)}$ is the vector $\left(
x_{1}^{(k)},x_{2}^{(k)},x_{3}^{(k)}\right) ^{T}$, $x^{(k+1)}$ is the vector $%
\left( x_{1}^{(k+1)},x_{2}^{(k+1)},x_{3}^{(k+1)}\right) ^{T}$, $J\left(
x^{(k)}\right) $ is the Jacobian matrix evaluated at $\left(
x_{1}^{(k)},x_{2}^{(k)},x_{3}^{(k)}\right) $ and $f\left( x^{(k)}\right)$ is the vector column $(8)$ of $f$ evaluated at $\left(
x_{1}^{(k)},x_{2}^{(k)},x_{3}^{(k)}\right) $.

Answer (score 0):

The first equation is used to substitute all $a \rightarrow \frac{3}{2}b+1500$. The two remaining equations can be collected into a `2x1` vector $f = 0$

$$f = \begin{pmatrix} \hat{e}^b-\frac{b}{300}-\frac{c}{200}-5 \\ \hat{e}^c-\frac{b}{200}+\frac{c}{200} \end{pmatrix} $$

The derivatives with respect to $b$ and $c$ for each part are

$$ f\,' =  \begin{pmatrix} \hat{e}^b-\frac{1}{300} & -\frac{1}{200} \\ -\frac{1}{200} & \hat{e}^c+\frac{1}{200} \end{pmatrix}  $$

Newton raphson with vectors is $ (b,c) \rightarrow (b,c) - {f\,'}^{-1} f $

$$ \begin{pmatrix}b\\c\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}b\\c\end{pmatrix} - 
\begin{pmatrix} \hat{e}^b-\frac{1}{300} & -\frac{1}{200} \\ -\frac{1}{200} & \hat{e}^c+\frac{1}{200} \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} \hat{e}^b-\frac{b}{300}-\frac{c}{200}-5 \\ \hat{e}^c-\frac{b}{200}+\frac{c}{200} \end{pmatrix}  $$

with an initial guess of $\begin{pmatrix}b = 1\\c = 1 \end{pmatrix} $ I get the following iterations

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\1.841661&0.003381327\\1.634514&-0.9835724\\1.608907&-1.936174\\1.607725&-2.783955\\1.607126&-3.380392 \end{bmatrix} $$

So in the end we have $ a= \frac{3}{2} 1.607126 + 1500 $, $ b = 1.607126 $, $ c = -3.380392 $.